# Mongoose - Filtrar resultados en un populate

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, mongoose

Estoy tratando de filtrar los datos de un populate, pero no me está regresado nada.

```
const productos = await models.Activosfijos.find({ $or: [{ 'Codigo': new RegExp(valor, 'i') }, { 'Descripcion': new RegExp(valor, 'i') }, { 'Marca': new RegExp(valor, 'i') }, { 'Grupo': new RegExp(valor, 'i') }] }, { createdAt: 0 })

                .populate('bodegas', {
                    match:{ $or: [{ 'Nombre': new RegExp(valor, 'i') }]}
                })
                .sort({ 'createdAt': -1 });
```

No logro hacer que funcione el filtro y la respuesta e siempre un json vacio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que tienes un error de sintaxis:

```js
 .populate('bodegas', {
    match:{ Nombre: { $or: new RegExp(valor, 'i') } }
}).sort({ 'createdAt': -1 });
```

populate documentation: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate